# Resizing the TMainMenu

Tags: delphi, menubar, ownerdrawn

I'm relatively new to programming and my problem is with a TMainMenu on my form.
I researched a lot 
 (a whole lot) of sites for a solution, but haven't found any that solves this exact problem. 
The main menu won't resize, not even when I change the fontsize using *Screen.MenuFont.Size*.
 I tried setting the *Height* property in the *OnMeasureItem* handler, I tried resizing the images and sub-menuitems at both design- and runtime, I even tried capturing Windows' message *WMDrawItem* and changing it's parameter before passing it on...

The menu items in the component are resized accordingly, but the vertical height of the menubar itself isn't. (the line seen on the picture below cutting through the icons)

Is there an easy solution to this, like setting some well hidden height property somewhere?
Or do I have to rewrite half of delphi's code to achieve my goal?
Help with code examples are appreciated. :-)

Here's an image:
[image]

I am using Delphi 7 on a Win7 machine.

Comment: You are probably expected to put 16px icons in there

Comment: That's my last resort if there isn't a way to do it with bigger icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use `TActionMainMenuBar` instead. It is much more flexible then the `TMainMenu`.
You can change the font of the menu bar very easy as well.

Answer (score 3):

The height of the menu bar is a Windows metric setting. Thus it is valid system wide - not only for your application. If at all, it can only be changed via the display settings of Windows itself.

Comment: Thank you! It's time for a different approach then.